# Using posix socket from a web application

Tags: javascript, sockets, web, localhost

I need to send and receive stuff from posix socket (on 127.0.0.1) and I need to do this from a web page.
I'm doing this right now with PHP, but I don't like this solution too much.
Is there a way to do this in ... javascript? Or what could be the best solution?

Regards